# MacTex 2015, not showing Nomenclature

Tags: mactex, nomenclature, latexian

Using MacTex 2015 distribution, and two different LaTeX editors (TexShop and Latexian), it is unable to show the nomenclature. I've tried in other computers and online Latex editors and I was successful, but not with MacTex 2015. I am doing 2 Typesetter Runs at the end and the code works on other computers. I have also tried reinstalling MacTex but the problem persists.

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass[twoside,openright]{report}
\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}
\makenomenclature

\begin{document}

\nomenclature{$\omega$}{Absolute Frequency}
\printnomenclature

\end{document}
```

Comment: What is an MWE (http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/231/1169)?

Comment: Welcome! Did you run `makeindex` (`nomencl`) or `makeglossaries` (`glossaries`) or similar (other package you are using)?

Comment: Yes, I did run `makeindex` but not working. Seems that I am missing something. I'm updating the question with a MWE.

Comment: `makeindex` will have created a log-file. Please check it out and post it, there will be clues in there.

Comment: I don't have that log-file, so I assume `makeindex` is not running, although I tick the makeindex option within Latexian. How can I make it run?

Comment: Are you sure? It should have the ending `ilg`. Best would be to test first on the command line that everything works, and later check what Latexian is doing.

Comment: No `ilg` files... The only place `makeindex` is mentioned is on the export window, it says: `/usr/texbin/makeindex TSWLatexianTemp_000004.idx` and it is empty.

Comment: Run everything on the command line so you know whether the problem is with your editor config or not.

Comment: It works when running everything on the command line, so I assume the problem is on Latexian editor. Although I tick the option to run makeindex, it seems incompatible with this last version of MaxTex distribution (maybe).

Answer (score 1):

It seems some text in the document itself is required for the indexing file to be written correctly on compilation.

```
\documentclass[twoside,openright]{report}
\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}
\makenomenclature

\begin{document}

Some text.

\nomenclature{$\omega$}{Absolute Frequency}
\printnomenclature

\end{document}
```

If you compile with some dummy text and then create the nomenclature, you can remove the dummy text afterwards and recompile to just get the nomenclature on its own (if that is desired).

So the steps are:

1. Add dummy text.
2. Compile.
3. Create nomenclature using `makeindex <filename>.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o <filename>.nls` as usual.
4. Remove dummy text.
5. Compile to get the nomenclature alone.

[image: just nomenclature]

Comment: Yes, the `\write` issued by `\index` (or variations thereof) is not `\immediate`, so if no page is shipped out you get no index.

Comment: @egreg Ah. Thanks for the explanation. So the `\write` is triggered when the page is shipped out?

Comment: Yes, otherwise `\index` could not know the actual page number.

Comment: @egreg OK. Yes. Now you say it, that makes sense. I wasn't thinking of page numbers (because there aren't any in this example) but I imagine they might be useful in an index!

Comment: I have done that and still not getting the Nomenclature. Is there a way to manually reinstall the `makeindex` engine in MacTex 2015?

Comment: @Alberto I don't know. I haven't used MacTeX for several years. It is quite unlikely that you need to reinstall it, though. What is the output when you run the compilation sequence? Better, can you post the `.log` files you get in your question?